# How can i copy contents from 1 string to another...

Tags: c#, string

I am a working on NER (named entity recognition) module with using unicode devnagri hindi.

I have two string. In the 1st one, we are taking all the contents of text box.

```
string[] s = richTextBox1.Text;
```

In the 2nd one, we wanna get sentences by splitting the contents with using "|" of 1st string (string s).

how could we declare 2nd string and how could we copy contents from string s to 2nd string.

Now, help us on this.....

Comment: your `s` is an array of string

Comment: sorry but this question seems just too silly to me. are you seriously asking how to declare string variable? and in two seconds after googling "c# string splitting" you would have an answer for it.

Answer (score 1):

I'll recommend you read up on the basics of [strings in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362.aspx). And after that, look into what arrays are. Perhaps start out with a good tutorial explaining you all the basics, before you bother with UI controls?

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> s = new List<string>;
s.Add(richTextBox1.Text);
s.AddRange(s[0].Split('|');

string[] strings = s.ToArray();
```

Be careful though, this can end up very costly (both performance and memory wise) if you use it frequently enough (many times a millisecond).

Answer (score 0):

If I read the question right, something like:

```
string[] sentences = richTextBox1.Text.Split('|');
```

Say your data in the textbox was `a|b|c`, then

`sentences[0]` will be equal to `a`, `sentences[1]` equal to `b` and so on.